# ggplot labels unit format

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend-properties

Hey i want to change the unit format

and this my code for y scales

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::unit_format(unit="Rp"))
```

and the output will be 400 000 Rp

but, i want the output to be like this, Rp 400 000

```
scale_x_continuous(labels = math_format(x^2)),
```

it give error message,
i want the output like this,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgCaw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `y` scales, use `prefix`

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::unit_format(prefix ="Rp ", unit = ""))
```

for `x`, dont forget a `.`

```
scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::math_format(expr = .x^2))
```

Comment: Yap, thats what i need
How about the axis title ? any idea to give it like that ?

Comment: try `scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::math_format(.x^2),
                     name = expression(axis_title^2))`

Comment: Ok, thats very helping for me
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can put `Rp` before the number:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0("Rp", x))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but i rather choose the other one, cause its more simple